# cocos2d-x 3 How to make sprite swallow all touches only on it

Tags: c++, cocos2d-x, cocos2d-x-3.0

I have a `main layer` that should get touch events. But on that layer there is a `navigation bar`, which has buttons and other sprites in it and is a subclass of `cocos2d::Sprite`. Now I need that all touches on `navigation bar` were not interpreted as touches on `main layer`. The buttons work correctly, but `navigation bar` sprite passes touches to `main layer`. I have done this to prevent passing events:

```
auto touchListenerOneByOne = EventListenerTouchOneByOne::create();
touchListenerOneByOne->setSwallowTouches(true);
touchListenerOneByOne->onTouchBegan = CC_CALLBACK_2(NavigationBar::onBoardTouchBegan, this);
_eventDispatcher->addEventListenerWithSceneGraphPriority(touchListenerOneByOne, this);


bool NavigationBar::onBoardTouchBegan(Touch* touch, Event* event)
{
    CCLOG("Navigation sprite is touched......!");
    return true;
}
```

This prevents passing, but it blocks - swallows all touches. Now I cannot pass any touch to the `main layer`, even if I don't touch the `navigation bar`. I have tried to use `setContentSize` but it does not help. Where is the solution?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Answer is here: http://www.cocos2d-x.org/wiki/How_To_Subclass_Sprite_And_Add_Event_Listeners

I have changed here the follwing things:

- `Vector2` to `Vec2`,
- removed second argument in `void touchEvent(cocos2d::Touch* touch, cocos2d::Vector2 _p);`
- `MySprite::touchEvent(touch);` to `touchEvent(touch);`
- `cocos2d::Director::getInstance()->getEventDispatcher()->addEventListenerWithFixedPriority(listener, 30);` to `_eventDispatcher->addEventListenerWithSceneGraphPriority(listener, this);`

It turns that the sprite should check if the touch is on it, than swallow but returning `true`in the `onTouchBegan`listener, otherwise `false`.

Comment: Link not available

Comment: For more context: https://discuss.cocos2d-x.org/t/cocos2d-x-3-how-to-make-sprite-swallow-all-touches-only-on-it/15094